# Accessing the host configuration inside the ASP.NET Core Startup methods

Tags: asp.net-core

On a typical ASP.NET Core application, the `Main` method creates a configuration and passes it to the `WebHostBuilder`. Is there a way to access this configuration inside any of the `Startup` methods (e.g. `Configure` or `ConfigureServices`)?

I need this configuration because it has access to the command line arguments.

Thanks

Pedro

Comment: All required informations are here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a property in the class, where `Main` method exists, to persist the configuration, or use any other class for storage.

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
```

From other side, you can read configuration few times. You are allowed to create another instance of `ConfigurationBuilder` and specify configuration sources (maybe even different than you use in main method):

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var anotherConfiguration = builder.Build();
```

Comment: The `Startup.Configuration` property would have to be static, since we don't have access to the `Startup` instance on the `Main` method, right?

Comment: @PedroFelix have updated answer, should be more clear right now. Regarding static - you should avoid such pattern, as it will complicate unit testing

Comment: @PedroFelix Check the [MusicStore example](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L28) to see how (and where) you would usually store the configuration object.

Comment: It doesn't have to be static. Register service or already build configuration in the services collection and inject it where ever you want.

Comment: @Set: the `Main` method is static, i.e., there isn't a `Program` instance, so the `Configuration` would have to be static. Even if using a property on a difference instance, how do I reach that instance in the `Startup` method, namely since the `Startup` instance is created by the framework?

@Poke, Dawid: Thanks. I'm aware of how to inject the configuration created on the `Startup` methods. However, I need to access the configuration created on the `Main` method, because I need to access the invocation args (`.AddCommandLine(args)`)